# Select query specific columns not retrieve data

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have created a stored procedure row into column (pivot table) with dynamic column name and convert into temp table. I create same as another table with table. After this process I join column both table common date column. But I need this table only 1 time date column.

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server`? Pick one!

Comment: **Pro Tip:** We cannot help you with a piece of code that we cannot see. Post the query code and the relevant table definitions from the  database schema

Comment: Only words are given, so my answer will also be words.  "I need this table only 1 time date column".  So only select 1 time.